# DecimalFormat and Arabic Locale

Tags: java, android, exception, mobile

I am using decimal format to get 2 numbers after '.', it's working fine when locale is US or FR but when locale is Ar(arabic) it gives me this error:

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "٠"

what is the solution?

```
 if ( !option1.equals("False")) {

                                        double result = (statistic1 / i[0]) * 1.0 * 100;
                                        result = Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(result));
                                        s1.setText(result + "%");
                                        o1.setText(option1);

                                    }
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem was that decimal format uses a locale for symbolizing the numbers, the solution was to make the decimal symbol default as Locale.US

```
final DecimalFormatSymbols decimalSymbol = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US);
                                        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
                                        df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(decimalSymbol);
```

Comment: does it matter if we use `Locale.US` or `Locale.ENGLISH` ?